# Restoring scroll position on a GridView at the right time

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I need to restore the scroll position of a GridView in my windows app. I'm trying to find the right time to call ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset() and have it succeed.

If I call it in the OnNavigatedTo override, it has no effect:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = LoadModel();
    RestoreScrollPos();
}
```

If I call it in the Loaded handler for the page, it has no effect.

```
private void onPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = LoadModel();
    RestoreScrollPos();
}
```

If I do something like the following, then it works but it is jarring because the GridView is first drawn at scroll position 0 and then snaps to the new scroll position.

```
    var dontAwaitHere =
      Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
      delegate()
      {
        RestoreScrollPos();
      });
```

If I try to repro this behavior from the default visual studio GridView project, it seems to work most of the time, but I did see it not work once. I believe there is some sort of race condition, and I suspect I am putting it in the wrong place.

QUESTION = Where should I call RestoreScrollPos() Or where should I look to debug this?

```
    private void RestoreScrollPos()
    {
      var scrollViewer = findScrollViewer(itemGridView);
      if (scrollViewer != null)
      {
        scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(100000.0); // TODO test
      }
    }

    public static ScrollViewer findScrollViewer(DependencyObject el)
    {
      ScrollViewer retValue = findDescendant<ScrollViewer>(el);
      return retValue;
    }

    public static tType findDescendant<tType>(DependencyObject el)
      where tType : DependencyObject
    {
      tType retValue = null;
      int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(el);

      for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
      {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(el, i);
        if (child is tType)
        {
          retValue = (tType)child;
          break;
        }

        retValue = findDescendant<tType>(child);

        if (retValue != null)
        {
          break;
        }
      }

      return retValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `RestoreScrollPos` only after the grid has finished loading:

```
public MyPageConstructor()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.itemGridView.Loaded += (s,e) => itemGridView_Loaded(s, e);
}

private void itemGridView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RestoreScrollPos();
}
```

As to where to load the data, you should try in `LoadState`:

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    DataContext = LoadModel();
    base.LoadState(navigationParameter, pageState);
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't do the trick either... same behavior as using the page's Loaded event :(

Comment: @swinefeaster - see my addition for where to load the data. My app does this exact same thing, so it does work (at least for me).

Comment: I did as you suggested... put the loading of my model in the page's loaded event and the restoring of the scroll pos in the gridview's loaded event but no luck. If I set a breakpoint on both, I see that the gridview's loaded event is hit first, followed by the page's loaded event. This won't work because if the page loaded event has not yet been triggered, we won't be able to restore the scroll position because there will be nowhere to scroll...